# Media player stops about every 5 minutes

Tags: video, vlc

I have a problem that's driving me crazy. After installing many YouTube ad free alternatives my media player (vlc, the one in the phone and another one) stop playing and give me error or ads. I've uninstalled everything but the problem persists. What can I do?

I uninstalled every YouTube app